# Phonegap black screen video tag on some kitkat android 4.4 devices (Minix X8 & Tronsmart S89)

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat, minix

In my Cordova application I use the HTML5 video tag to display videos.
This worked just fine, but somehow the mp4/3gp/mov videos do not work on the Android 4.4.2 based media players: Minix X8 & Tronsmart S89. My Sony Xperia Z1 which also runs on 4.4.2 plays all videos without a problem. So does the older Minix X7 running Android 4.2.

Webm videos work just fine, but every other format refuses to show the video. When I look at the timeline it does count and when I click full screen I get one real short flash of the video that is playing and then the screen turns black again. When I open the browser and go directly to the video, it does play on the Minix X8, but doesn't on the Tronsmart S89.

I'm not using any plugins for the video player. I have seen there are some, but I need to play the video within the application view and not in a external video player.

Do you guys have any idea what the problem could be?